# Blender Add-on Dev: Unregister is never called on Blender Exit?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

In my add-on `__init__.py` file, I have a function defined `def unregister():` which unregisters all other modules. But when I exit Blender normally (Windows 10, X button), this function is never called.

**Edit Note: This is normal behavior - see answer**

Is there something that needs to be done before Blender executes `unregister()` on exit? Or perhaps some error in my add-on may be causing this behavior? I get no warnings or errors. Only two lines print out on exit:

```
Saved session recovery to 'C:\Users\Moats\AppData\Local\Temp\quit.blend'
Blender quit
```

Maybe this is normal? Blender is saying - its over, so it doesn't matter? One other unlikely possibility is that print() doesn't function after a certain exit point. I can probably confirm this, but not easily.

If anyone knows what might be happening, or can confirm that their own `unregister()` is being called on exit, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The `unregister()` function is only called when you deactivate the add-on in your preferences, as far as I'm aware. Add-ons that store settings in the preferences commonly remove them when `unregister()` is called. It would be very inconvenient if that was the case whenever Blender is closed. For an example see the add-on in this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153022/pycharm-remote-debugger/153031

Comment: Yeah, I'm still finding my way around in this area. I assumed `register()` was a sort of activation area, and 'unregister()' was the exit point of that activation. I just assumed all add-ons would be deactivated before Blender shuts down. I've noticed several add-ons doing this, so it must be a common assumption (unless they were only trying to clean up for add-on toggling). So then it would be unwise to try to initialize in `register()` and clean up in `unregister()`? Such as, for example, to flush some file buffers on exit (random example). Where would be the best place to do this?

Comment: The add-ons unregister the classes that they have registered and delete types that they have created. They shouldn't do anything that needs to be executed when Blender terminates (because the `unregister()` function doesn't get called when that happends). If anything needs to run when Blender closes you would use `atexit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Since commit [rBfa566157a5c351775d082b05b180c630665b4afc](https://developer.blender.org/rBfa566157a5c351775d082b05b180c630665b4afc) Blender calls unregister on exit in `WM_exit_ex` through `addon_utils.disable_all()`. This only calls `unregister` for the installed and enabled add-ons though, not for scripts run from the text editor.

You can verify this by saving the script below in a `.py` file, installing and enabling it as an add-on in *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons* and then closing Blender. The `test.txt` file will contain the `"unregister"` line when using Blender 2.91 or later, assuming that you have the required permissions to write the file.

---

**Old answer that applies to versions prior to commit [rBfa566157a5c351775d082b05b180c630665b4afc](https://developer.blender.org/rBfa566157a5c351775d082b05b180c630665b4afc)**

The `unregister()` function is only called when you deactivate the add-on in your preferences, while `register()` is always called when Blender starts in case the add-on is activated in the preferences. You can test this with the following simple add-on that writes into a text file whenever one of the functions is executed. The example also includes how to add a handler that is triggered when Blender is exiting.

*This add-on tries to write the test file into Blender's install directory. If that directory requires special permissions, then you should adjust the path to somewhere it can write the file to.*

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Register and unregister test",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "Dummy panel in View3D",
    "description": "Check when register and unregister are called",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy
import atexit


class EXAMPLE_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My own addon"
    bl_category = "Name of your tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="This is a label")


classes = (EXAMPLE_PT_panel,)


def exit_handler():
    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("exiting\n")

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("register\n")
    atexit.register(exit_handler)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("unregister\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Extremely helpful, thank you. I was not able to find `atexit` in the manuals. I'm assuming that Is a python level event? Do you happen to know in what order it would call the event handler? Or rather, at what point in Blender's shutdown sequence `exit_handler()` would be called? I can probably figure this out with `print()` tracking, but if you have any experience using it, I appreciate any details. Anyway, thanks for this detailed example. It shows exactly how to use it.

Comment: It's a Python feature which is run when/before the interpreter is terminated. https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48565/how-to-run-a-python-callback-when-blender-exits

Comment: My bad - I tried to find something like this, but apparently didn't use great search terms. Thanks again. Huge help.

Comment: Related question that I think you may be able to answer, @RobertGützkow :
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260235/blender-python-addon-doesnt-unregister-registers-fine