# Blender Python Addon doesn't unregister (registers fine)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties, panel

Disclaimer: I'm new to Blender Python. Thank you in advance for your assistance, and patience. I saw [this related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153084/blender-add-on-dev-unregister-is-never-called-on-blender-exit) but I'm not sure it applies here.

I am developing an addon with a panel class that doesn't unregister when I disable the addon in blender preferences. Not even when I remove the addon. The panel won't be removed unless I restart blender after disabling/removing the addon. So even after removing the addon, I'm left with this panel until I restart blender:

[image]

I'm not sure what blender is looking for on the back end when enabling and disabling addons, and having a look at blender's documentation hasn't cleared things up for me. So I'm hoping the wonderful community can shed some light here. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code

```
bl_info = {
    "Cam-Shape-Matic" : "CamShpMtc",   
    "category": "3D View",   
    "author": "BeyondDev",
    "blender": (2, 8, 0),
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "category": "Object",
    "description": "Drive Shapekeys on Objects based on Relative Camera Angle.",
    "doc_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
}
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
import bpy
import mathutils


# To workaround the "known bug with using a callback" mentioned
# in the EnumProperty docs, this function needs to be called on
# any EnumProperty's items.
ENUM_STRING_CACHE = {}
def intern_enum_items_strings(items):
    def intern_string(s):
        if isinstance(s, str):
            ENUM_STRING_CACHE.setdefault(s, s)
            s = ENUM_STRING_CACHE[s]
        return s

    return [
        tuple([intern_string(s) for s in item])
        for item in items
    ]


# This callback will return a list of enum items in the usual
# [(identifier, name, description), ...] format.
def my_shapekey_enum_items_callback(self, context):
    items = []

    if self and self.shape_keys:
        items = [
            (kb.name, kb.name, '')
            for i, kb in enumerate(self.shape_keys.key_blocks)
        ]

    return intern_enum_items_strings(items)


# This callback will return a list of enum items in the usual
# [(identifier, name, description), ...] format.
def my_object_enum_items_callback(self, context):
    items = []

    if  bpy.context.window and bpy.context.window.view_layer:
        items = [
            (ob.name, ob.name, '')
            for i, ob in enumerate(bpy.context.window.view_layer.objects) if bpy.context.window.view_layer.objects[i].type == 'MESH'
        ]

    return intern_enum_items_strings(items)


def my_bone_enum_items_callback(self, context):
    items = []
    selObj = bpy.context.window_manager.object
    selArmatureParse = bpy.data.objects[selObj].find_armature().name.split('_') #parse returned name 'Object_rig' into list [Object, rig]
    selArmature = selArmatureParse[len(selArmatureParse)-1] #get name of rig from last item in parsed list (above)

    if  bpy.context.window and bpy.context.window.view_layer and selArmature:
        items = [
            (ob.name, ob.name, '')
            for i, ob in enumerate(bpy.data.armatures[selArmature].bones) if bpy.data.armatures[selArmature].bones[i].use_deform == True
        ]

    return intern_enum_items_strings(items)
    

class CamShapeMaticPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'CamShpMtc'
    bl_label = "CamShapeMatic"
    bl_idname = "MAIN_PT_camshapematic_panel"    

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        box = layout.box()
        col = box.column(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)

        col.separator()
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.scale_y = 1.1
        row.prop(context.window_manager, "EnableCamShapeMatic", text="Enable/Disable Shape Changes")

        scene = context.scene

        col.separator()
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.label(text='Select Camera')
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.scale_y = 1.1
        row.prop(scene, "camera")
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.scale_y = 1.1
        row.prop(context.window_manager, "AngleSensitivity", text="Cam Angle Sensitivity")

        col.separator()
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.label(text='Select Object')
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.scale_y = 1.1
        row.prop(context.window_manager, "object", icon="MESH_MONKEY", text='Mesh')

        selObj = bpy.context.window_manager.object
        AngleSens = bpy.context.window_manager.AngleSensitivity
        Enable = bpy.context.window_manager.EnableCamShapeMatic

        # draw shapekey_top/bottom/left/right for the current object
        # only if it's a mesh with shapekeys though
        if (
            bpy.data and
            bpy.data.objects and
            bpy.data.objects[selObj].type == 'MESH' and
            bpy.data.objects[selObj].data.shape_keys
        ):            
            
            col.separator()
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.label(text='Select Shapekeys')

            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.scale_y = 1.1
            row.prop(bpy.data.objects[selObj].data, "shapekey_top", icon='SHAPEKEY_DATA', text='Top')
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.scale_y = 1.1
            row.prop(bpy.data.objects[selObj].data, "shapekey_bottom", icon='SHAPEKEY_DATA', text='Bottom')
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.scale_y = 1.1
            row.prop(bpy.data.objects[selObj].data, "shapekey_left", icon='SHAPEKEY_DATA', text='Left')
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.scale_y = 1.1
            row.prop(bpy.data.objects[selObj].data, "shapekey_right", icon='SHAPEKEY_DATA', text='Right')
        
        
        # If the selected object has an armature
        if (
            bpy.data and
            bpy.data.objects and
            bpy.data.objects[selObj].find_armature()
        ):
            col.separator()
            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.label(text='Select Bone (ex: Head Bone)')

            row = col.row(align=True)
            row.scale_y = 1.1
            row.prop(context.window_manager, "bone", icon='BONE_DATA', text='Deform Bone')
            row = col.row(align=True)



        # only if it's a mesh with shapekeys though
        if (
            bpy.data and
            bpy.data.objects and
            bpy.data.objects[selObj].type == 'MESH' and
            bpy.data.objects[selObj].data.shape_keys and
            Enable == True
        ):    


            if bpy.data.objects[selObj].data.shapekey_top != NULL:

                cam = bpy.context.scene.camera
                obj = bpy.data.objects[selObj]

                if (
                    bpy.data and
                    bpy.data.objects and
                    bpy.data.objects[selObj].find_armature()
                ):
                    selArmature = bpy.data.objects[selObj].find_armature().name
                    rot = bpy.data.objects[selArmature].pose.bones[bpy.context.window_manager.bone]
                    self.obj_eul = rot.matrix.to_euler('XYZ') #this works for an obj OR a bone, world space
                    self.loc = rot.matrix.to_translation()
                else:
                    rot = bpy.data.objects[selObj]
                    self.obj_eul = rot.rotation_euler
                    self.loc = rot.location

                def drive_shapekey(scene, post):

                    try:
                        del line
                    except:
                        pass

                    objKey = obj.data.shape_keys #bpy.data.shapekeys["Key.00_"]


                    if Enable == True:
                        #LEFT -----------------------------------------------------
                        #obj_eul = rot.rotation_euler
                        cam_vec = self.loc - cam.matrix_world.to_translation()
                        cam_vec = cam_vec.normalized()*mathutils.Vector((1.0,1.0,0.0))
                        obj_vec = mathutils.Vector((-1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
                        obj_vec.rotate(self.obj_eul)
                        difference = cam_vec.dot(obj_vec)

                        shapekey_Name = obj.data.shapekey_left #Name of shapekey
                        key_left = objKey.key_blocks[shapekey_Name] #Datapath ending for shapekey value
                        key_left.value = difference*AngleSens

                        #RIGHT -----------------------------------------------------
                        #obj_eul = rot.rotation_euler
                        cam_vec = self.loc - cam.matrix_world.to_translation()
                        cam_vec = cam_vec.normalized()*mathutils.Vector((1.0,1.0,0.0))
                        obj_vec = mathutils.Vector((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
                        obj_vec.rotate(self.obj_eul)
                        difference = cam_vec.dot(obj_vec)

                        shapekey_Name = obj.data.shapekey_right #Name of shapekey
                        key_right = objKey.key_blocks[shapekey_Name] #Datapath ending for shapekey value
                        key_right.value = difference*AngleSens

                        #TOP -----------------------------------------------------
                        #obj_eul = rot.rotation_euler
                        cam_vec = self.loc - cam.matrix_world.to_translation()
                        cam_vec = cam_vec.normalized()*mathutils.Vector((0.0,1.0,1.0))
                        obj_vec = mathutils.Vector((0.0, -1.0, 0.0)) #without rotate math below, this should be (0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
                        obj_vec.rotate(self.obj_eul)
                        difference = cam_vec.dot(obj_vec)

                        shapekey_Name = obj.data.shapekey_top #Name of shapekey
                        key_top = objKey.key_blocks[shapekey_Name] #Datapath ending for shapekey value
                        key_top.value = difference*AngleSens - key_right.value - key_left.value

                        line = [self.loc, cam.location]

                        #BOTTOM -----------------------------------------------------
                        #obj_eul = rot.rotation_euler
                        cam_vec = self.loc - cam.matrix_world.to_translation()
                        cam_vec = cam_vec.normalized()*mathutils.Vector((0.0,1.0,1.0))
                        obj_vec = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.0)) #without rotate math below, this should be (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                        obj_vec.rotate(self.obj_eul)
                        difference = cam_vec.dot(obj_vec)

                        shapekey_Name = obj.data.shapekey_bottom #Name of shapekey
                        key_bottom = objKey.key_blocks[shapekey_Name] #Datapath ending for shapekey value
                        key_bottom.value = difference*AngleSens - key_right.value - key_left.value


            pre_handlers_scene = bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre #Drive Shapekey on schene updates
            pre_handlers_anim = bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre #Drive shapekey before frame changes
            pre_handlers_render = bpy.app.handlers.render_pre #Drive shapekey during renders
            
            [pre_handlers_scene.remove(h) for h in pre_handlers_scene if h.__name__ == "drive_shapekey"]
            pre_handlers_scene.append(drive_shapekey)

            [pre_handlers_anim.remove(h) for h in pre_handlers_anim if h.__name__ == "drive_shapekey"]
            pre_handlers_anim.append(drive_shapekey) 

            [pre_handlers_render.remove(h) for h in pre_handlers_render if h.__name__ == "drive_shapekey"]
            pre_handlers_render.append(drive_shapekey) 


classes = [CamShapeMaticPanel]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
    bpy.types.WindowManager.object = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name="Selected Object",
    description="Select an object",
    items=my_object_enum_items_callback,
    )
    
    bpy.types.WindowManager.bone = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name="Selected Bone",
    description="Select a bone",
    items=my_bone_enum_items_callback,
    )

    bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_top = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Top Shapekey",
        description="Select a shapekey",
        items=my_shapekey_enum_items_callback,
    )

    bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_bottom = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Bottom Shapekey",
        description="Select a shapekey",
        items=my_shapekey_enum_items_callback,
    )

    bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_left = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Left Shapekey",
        description="Select a shapekey",
        items=my_shapekey_enum_items_callback,
    )

    bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_right = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Right Shapekey",
        description="Select a shapekey",
        items=my_shapekey_enum_items_callback,
    )

    bpy.types.WindowManager.AngleSensitivity = bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=1.5, max=2.0, min=1.0)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.EnableCamShapeMatic = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.object
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.bone
    del bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_top
    del bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_bottom
    del bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_left
    del bpy.types.Mesh.shapekey_right
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.AngleSensitivity
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.EnableCamShapeMatic
    
if __name__ == "__main__" or __name__ == "CamShapeMatic":
    register()
```

Comment: I would delete the 4 last lines and put the `bpy.types...` custom properties definitions in both the register and unregister with `del bpy.types....` otherwise I think you'll still have a bunch of custom properties associated with your objects after disabling the addon

Comment: @Gorgious thanks for those tips! It makes sense that I should be only defining those bpy.types in the reg and ureg functions. However, by removing those bottom 4 lines of code my addon panel doesn't show up at all after enabling the addon from preferences. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your main problem is your `bl_info` structure. You can read about it in the [Blender official wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo) Here's a corrected version:

```py
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Cam-Shape-Matic",  
    "category": "3D View",   
    "author": "BeyondDev",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "description": "Drive Shapekeys on Objects based on Relative Camera Angle.",
    "doc_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
}
```

- You had a field that Blender didn't recognize.  I removed it.
- You didn't have a `name` field. I added it
- You had two `category` fields.  I deleted the second one, as the first one is what you wanted.
- You had `8` as the minor version number in the `Blender` field.  It should be `80`. I replaced it.

Having done that, I can now install your add-on using this technique:

1. Create a directory called `Cam-Shape-Matic`.
2. Place the modified code in the directory in a file called `__init__.py`
3. Zip the directory into `Cam-Sphae-Matic.zip`
4. Use the "install" command of *preferences* → *addons* to install it.

Having done that, if I disable or remove the addon using the Preferences command, the `unregister()` function is properly called.

I did not debug the addon's code, of course.

The only other change needed is that this line:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__" or __name__ == "CamShapeMatic":
```

should be

```py
if __name__ == "__main__"
```

`__main__` is a *special variable*.  You can read about how it is used [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__name__-special-variable-python/).  Or you can read the [Python manual entry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) for details.

The convention in Blender is to place test code inside this if block, such as a test for registering your classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer and the revised code! You fixed even more than necessary, and helped my understanding greatly. Cheers!

Comment: @Tyler you're very welcome.  I'm sure you'll enjoy writing add-ons now.